# string split into all possible combination

Tags: string, algorithm, split

for a given string "ABC", i wish to get all the possible character combination out of it ascendingly and without skip of character, the result should be:["A","B","C"],["AB","C"],["ABC"],["A","BC"]

Any idea how can i achieve this? I was thinking using a nested for loop to get all the component:

```
string input="ABCD";
List<string> component=new List<string>();

for(int i=0;i<=input.Length;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<=(input.Length-i);j++){
        component.Add(input.Substring(i,j));
    }
}
```

But i have no idea how to put them into group as the above result. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You could consider the splits instead of the substrings. In your example, you have A|B|C, A·B|C, A·B·C, A|B·C, where | is a split and · is no split. For a string of N letters, you'll get 2^(N − 1) possible split patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go about this in several ways.

One way is **recursion**. Keep a current list of substrings and an overall results list.  At the top level, iterate over all the possible gaps. Split the string into a substring and the rest. This should include the "gap" at the end, where you split the string into itself and the empty string as rest. Add the (non-empty) substring to the current list and recurse on the rest of the string. When the rest of the string is empty, add the current list to the overall results list. This will give you all 2ⁿ possibilities for a string with *n* + 1 letters.

Pseudocode:

```
// recursive function
function splits_r(str, current, res)
{
    if (str.length == 0) {
        res += [current]
    } else {
        for (i = 0;  i < str.length; i++) {
            splits_r(str.substr(i + 1, end),
                current + [str.substr(0, i + 1)], res)
        }
    }
}

// wrapper to get the recursion going                
function splits(str)
{
    res = [];

    splits_r(str, [], res);

    return res;
}
```

Another way is **enumeration** of all possibilities. There are 2ⁿ possibilities for a string with *n* + 1 letters. You can consider one individual posibility as a combination of splits and non-splits. For example:

```
enum        splits              result                  

0 0 0       A   B   C   D       "ABCD"                  
0 0 1       A   B   C | D       "ABC", "D"              
0 1 0       A   B | C   D       "AB", "CD"              
0 1 1       A   B | C | D       "AB", "C", "D"          
1 0 0       A | B   C   D       "A", "BCD"              
1 0 1       A | B   C | D       "A", "BC", "D"          
1 1 0       A | B | C   D       "A", "B", "CD"          
1 1 1       A | B | C | D       "A", "B", "C", "D"
```

The enumeration uses 0 for no split and 1 for a split. It can be seen as a binary number. If you are familiar with [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C), you can now enumerate all values from 0 to 2ⁿ and find out where the splits are.

Pseudocode:

```
function splits(str)
{
    let m = str.length - 1;     // possible gap positions
    let n = (1 << m);           // == pow(2, m)
    let res = []

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
        let last = 0
        let current = []

        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {   // loop over all gaps
            if (i & (1 << j)) {     // test for split
                current.append(str.substr(last, j + 1));
                last = j + 1;
            }
        }

        current.append(s[last:])        
        res.append(current);

    return res;
}
```